# how to debug faulty hardware that causes freezing

Tags: hardware

I have an old desktop box that seems to freeze quite often while running Ubuntu. Sometimes it takes 1-2 min after boot, sometimes 30 min, sometimes it can run for days just fine. Upon freezing the screen just stays constant, and no mouse or keyboard input works (there is no screen of death).

I am pretty confident it is a hardware problem, so want to replace the motherboard, the cpu , the video card (nvidia) or the power supply. I need some help to figure out which one is the faulty one. I rejected the memory because I can run memtest for extensive period of time without any issues.

Which logs in Ubuntu would point me to a possible hardware failure on reboot after a freeze? Or what tools can stress test different components.

Comment: If you have onboard graphics, you can try that. This sounds like it might be a driver issue though..

Comment: It is unlikely to be PSU in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Rado. I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution in the end?